# Finding the Limit of a complex rational function

Tags: limits, rational-functions

How can I show that the following statement is true:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}}{(n+2)^{(n+1)^2}n^{n^2}} = \frac{1}{e}$$

This rather messy looking limit is the result of a ratio-test for convergence I am working on. I can get all the way to the left side of the equation, and when a solution wasn't forthcoming I used Mathematica to get the limit just to see where I should be headed and it said that it was equal to $\frac{1}{e}$ but despite over an hour of trial and error I can't figure out what I need to do to cause things to cancel or simplify down to a form whose limit I can show to be the aforementioned value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching to logarithms, we have to deal with

$$\left[(n+1)^2+n^2\right]\log(n+1)-(n+1)^2\log(n+2)-n^2\log n $$
that can be written as
$$ n^2\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}- (n+1)^2 \int_{n+1}^{n+2}\frac{dx}{x} $$
or as
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{n^2}{n+x}-\frac{(n+1)^2}{n+1+x}\right)\,dx =-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n^2+n+(2n+1)x}{(n+x)(n+1+x)}\,dx.$$
If we define $f_n(x)$ as $\frac{n^2+n+(2n+1)x}{(n+x)(n+1+x)}$, for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=1$, hence the claim follows from the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem):
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}}{(n+2)^{(n+1)^2}n^{n^2}}=\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{1}1\,dx\right) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{e}}.$$